# Build periodically only when other projects succeeds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have following configuration on jenkins -

[image]

I want to run my project periodically *only* in the night 11:46 and only when last run of when Obs-ProjectTests succeeds. But my project is built as soon as Obs-ProjectTests is built. How do I make my project build periodically only when last run of Obs-ProjectTests was successful and not on each trigger of Obs-ProjectTests ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate trigger job (say *Trigger-My-Project*) that will be always build at 11:46 PM and that checks the status of *Obs-ProjectTests* and triggers *My-Project* as a downstream job if the status is ok.

The check can be performed e.g. using a shell step and Jenkins XML-api:

```
wget -q -O- "$JENKINS_URL/job/Obs-ProjectTests/lastBuild/api/xml?xpath=//result" | grep SUCCESS
```

Then configure the **Post-build Actions** > **Build other projects** to trigger *My-Project* with **Trigger only if build is stable** set.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this without creating another job ```Trigger-My-Project``` ?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible.